# How to enable HiDPI resolutions in macOS Mojave

Tags: display, video, hdmi, resolution

I just picked up a LG C2 4K monitor and connecting it via HDMI to my 2009 Mac Pro via RX580 video card. I can get 120HZ and 4k resolutions, and there is a 1080P resolution option, but I cannot find any HiDPI resolutions.

My goal is to get a 1080P (HiDPI) resolution so that the images and text are larger and more clear.

Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible, and if so, how do I go about doing it?

Thank you.